# When I draw a button, it snaps back to the middle of the screen?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I'm very new to WPF. I was trying to add a button to a tab item (of a tab control I had already dragged in) in Visual C# 2010 Express. Upon doing this, the button repeatedly snapped to the center of the screen when I tried to drag-and-drop reposition it. Why is this happening, and how can I move the button? I haven't written any code, and the only properties of the button that I've changed are the size, content, and name.

Comment: My advice is to get used to using the XAML window (or the logical tree window) to understand what's going on with the layout - I'm not saying use it exclusively, but for fine tuned control or troubleshooting it's very useful.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same/similar problem today. In my case the designer had created a **`<border></border>`** around my button, with size equal to the whole application window. So, when I was moving my button around I was actually **moving the border and the button** and the border was snapping to the application and the button - to the border. When I removed the border - all was fixed.

### Diagram explanation

[image]

See if you have such a border or **other encapsulating element** which may cause this behaviour.